# React router doesn't work correctly in nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

React router works with one extra parameter in URL 
but when add another parameter like /panel-admin/dashboard 
doesn't work, 
i add this code

```
 location / {
           try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this?

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: What result do you get?